# trying to output JSON values within the same JSON object

Tags: php, json

Right now my php file outputs JSON like this:

```json
[
  {"category":142,"review_id":92},
  {"category":383,"review_id":353},
  {"category":203,"review_id":149},
  {"category":239,"review_id":355},
  {"category":239,"review_id":201},
  {"category":183,"review_id":59},
  {"category":183,"review_id":62}
]
```

But I want it to output like this:

```json
[
  {"category":142,"review_id":92},
  {"category":383,"review_id":353},
  {"category":203,"review_id":149},
  {"category":239,"review_id":355,"review_id":201},
  {"category":183,"review_id":59, "review_id":62}
]
```

Instead of the `category` number being repeated, I want the `review_ids` coming up within that same object. Can you tell me how I can do this please?

Here is my code:

```php
$user_id = "21";

//Select all related info in the review_shared table 
//where the contact_id column is equal to $user_id.

//a value in the contact_id column means a review is shared with a person, $user_name,
//who owns that number, $user_id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM review_shared WHERE contact_id = ?";
$stmt2 = $con->prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$stmt2->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
$stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();

$results = array();

//fetch all rows associated with the respective contact_id value
//in review_shared table
while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    //get the corresponding cat_id in the row
    $cat_id = $row["cat_id"];

    //get the corresponding review_id in the row
    $review_id = $row["review_id"];

    //make an array called $results
    $results[] = array(
            //get the corresponding cat_name in the row
            'category' => $row['cat_id'],  
            'review_id' => $review_id,
        );
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

I was trying code like:

```php
$review_id_results[] = array('review_id' => $review_id);
```

but don't know how to do it correctly and wasn't sure what to do exactly.

Comment: Neither PHP nor JSON allow arrays with multiple values for the same key. You need to chose a different format for your wanted output.

Comment: `{"category":239,"review_id":355,"review_id":201},` You're reassigning the key `review_id`.

Comment: You mean the output should be like, `{"category":183,"review_id":59, 62}` ? How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: what you really want is `{"category":183,"review_ids": [355, 201]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have duplicate proprieties on an object. What you really want is to have all yours `review_ids` listed as an array. Something like this:

```
$results = array();

//fetch all rows associated with the respective contact_id value
//in review_shared table
while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    //get the corresponding cat_id in the row
    $cat_id = $row["cat_id"];

    //get the corresponding review_id in the row
    $review_id = $row["review_id"];

    //make an array called $results
    $results[$row['cat_id']][] = $review_id; 
}

$jsonData = array_map(function($catId) use ($results) {
    return [
        'category' => $catId,
        'review_ids' => $results[$catId]
    ];
}, array_keys($results));

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

The end results will be

```
[{"category":123,"review_ids":[1,2]},{"category":456,"review_ids":[3]}]
```